# Xpath, why does it matches both?

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes, limit, predicate

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b>
      <ba>
        <baa>RM</baa>
        <bab>*DB:ZA:4</bab>
      </ba>
    </b>
    <c>
      <ca>M</ca>
      <cb>1</cb>
    </c>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>
      <ba>
        <baa>RM</baa>
        <bab>*DB:ZA:4</bab>
      </ba>
    </b>
    <c>
      <ca>S</ca>
      <cb>1</cb>
    </c>
  </a>
</root>
```

And the following xPath:
`//a[//bab/text() = '*DB:ZA:4' and //ca/text() = 'S']`

This returns both 'a' nodes. But I only want the one with ca='S'

I can achieve that by using `.//ca/text() = 'S'`. But I don't know why. Can someone epxlain?
Does the xpath loses the context where it is after the 'and' ?

I used this XPath-Tester: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because locator like `element[//anotherElement]` - returns `element`, but ensures that somewhere `anotherElement` is present.

And locator `element[.//anotherElement]` - returns element `element` for which there's descendant `anotherElement`.

Adding dot, in that case, changes search from absolute to relative path.

Answer (score 1):

`//ca/text() = 'S'` starts from the root of the document, so it will always select a text node with the content 'S' regardless of which `a` element is the context.

Use `.//ca/text()` instead, as this searches within the context of the current node.

Answer (score 1):

`//` will return elements located anywhere in the document, starting from root. `.//` will search relative to current node. It may be misleading, because you might think that using it inside a[] is already relative. It's the same with absolute expressions `/` and `./`.